# How do I center an Excel table pasted into Outlook with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a formatting issue with one section of my code.

This does everything I need except center alignment:

```vb
'Copy contents

    Sheets("Tables").Select
    Range("J6:R145").Select
    Range("J6").Activate
    Selection.Copy

'Open new mail item

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
   
'Get Word editor

    outMail.Display
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
   
'Paste as image
   
    wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    wordDoc.Range.Select
    Selection.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
```

Current Result: Failed Debug Step
[image]

Here's what I've plugged in so far:

```vb
Selection.PageSetup.CenterHorizontally = True
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

and the above-listed `Rows.Alignment`.

All have failed out at this line rather than centering the object.

Also how do I keep it from deleting the email signature when it pastes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Public Sub pastetable()
'Copy contents

    Sheets("Tables").Select
    Range("J6:R145").Select
    Range("J6").Activate
    Selection.Copy

'Open new mail item

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
   
'Get Word editor

    outMail.Display
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
   
'Paste as image
    wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create new empty paragraph before signature
    wordDoc.Paragraphs.first.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    
    With wordDoc.Tables(1).Rows
        .WrapAroundText = 0 'If this is true does not work
        .Alignment = 1
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a dream! Thank you!
Just for my own understanding, after PasteAndFormat the table it reference becomes "Tables(1)"? I'm assuming later tables would +1 that value if I were to repeat this process later in the code.

I've figured most of the essential functions I need for automation, but it's all coming down to aesthetic formatting now 

Comment: Yes, each new table will be added to the tables collection. Did it work keeping the signature?

Comment: It worked perfectly, and I'm already attempting to repurpose for the full use case. If possible, could you look at this question as well?  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75503267/vba-excel-to-outlook-separating-pasted-tables)  I'm sure it has to do with the answer you just gave me, but I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. I tried wordDoc.Tables(2),(3),etc. but I feel like I'm missing another piece.