# Separating Excel tables pasted to Outlook mail

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm running Excel VBA code to copy/paste/format emails to simplify reports.

The macro runs through several separate ranges in a worksheet. For each range it copies the selected area, pastes it into the email and centers the pasted table.

This is an expansion on my previous question:
[How Do I Center a Pasted Table with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75489739/how-do-i-center-a-pasted-excel-table-in-outlook-with-vba/75490608#75490608)

Even with `.Range.InsertParagraphBefore` to create a new line, my tables are nesting inside of each other as they load.

***Dims for Context:***

```vb
Sub Macro7()
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim outMail As Object
    Dim Location As String
    Dim Signature As String
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

'Open new mail item
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
'Get Word editor
    outMail.Display
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
```

***Problem Code:***

```vb
'Copy contents
    Sheets("Tables").Select
    Range("AB7:AI75").Select
    Range("AB7").Activate
    Selection.Copy

'Paste as image (Centered)
    wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create new empty paragraph before signature
    wordDoc.Paragraphs.first.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphBefore
    
    With wordDoc.Tables(1).Rows
        .WrapAroundText = 0 'If this is true does not work
        .Alignment = 1
    End With
    
'======== SECOND TABLE ========
'Copy contents (2)
    Sheets("Tables").Select
    Range("P7:Z29").Select
    Range("P7").Activate
    Selection.Copy
   
'Paste as image (Centered)(2)
    wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphBefore
    wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create new empty paragraph before signature
    wordDoc.Paragraphs.first.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    
    With wordDoc.Tables(1).Rows
        .WrapAroundText = 0 'If this is true does not work
        .Alignment = 1
    End With
    
'======== THIRD TABLE ==========
'Copy contents (3)

    Sheets("Tables").Select
    Range("F7:M30").Select
    Range("F7").Activate
    Selection.Copy
   
'Paste as image (Centered)(3)
    wordDoc.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create new empty paragraph before signature
    wordDoc.Paragraphs.first.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    
    With wordDoc.Tables(1).Rows
        .WrapAroundText = 0 'If this is true does not work
        .Alignment = 1
    End With
```

[image: Nested Tables in Email]

Each pasted table is dropped inside of the top line of the table before, nesting one inside the other, and I'm looking for a way to break them apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pastes the tables sequentially one after the other (not before the other), the idea os you look for the last paragraph and use the .previous property to insert the table in the paragraph before the last paragraph that it has been created on the lines before.

```
Sub Macro7()
' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim outMail As Object
    Dim Location As String
    Dim Signature As String
    
    
    
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

'Open new mail item

    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
'Get Word editor

    outMail.Display
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
'Copy contents

    Sheets("Tables").Select
    Range("AB7:AI75").Select
    Range("AB7").Activate
    
    Selection.Copy

'Paste as image (Centered)
    
    Dim insertPoint As Object
    wordDoc.Paragraphs.first.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create new empty paragraph before signature
    Set insertPoint = wordDoc.Paragraphs.first
    insertPoint.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create another
    insertPoint.Previous.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    
    With wordDoc.Tables(1).Rows
        .WrapAroundText = 0 'If this is true does not work
        .Alignment = 1
    End With
   
'======== SECOND TABLE ========
'Copy contents (2)

    Sheets("Tables").Select
    Range("P7:Z29").Select
    Range("P7").Activate
    Selection.Copy
   
'Paste as image (Centered)(2)
    
    insertPoint.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create new empty paragraph before signature
    insertPoint.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create another
    insertPoint.Previous.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    
    
    With wordDoc.Tables(2).Rows
        .WrapAroundText = 0 'If this is true does not work
        .Alignment = 1
    End With
    
    
'======== THIRD TABLE ==========
'Copy contents (3)

    Sheets("Tables").Select
    Range("F7:M30").Select
    Range("F7").Activate
    Selection.Copy
   
'Paste as image (Centered)(3)
    
    insertPoint.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create new empty paragraph before signature
    insertPoint.Range.InsertParagraphBefore 'Create another
    insertPoint.Previous.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
    
    With wordDoc.Tables(3).Rows
        .WrapAroundText = 0 'If this is true does not work
        .Alignment = 1
    End With

End Sub

``
```

Comment: So this is *very* close to exactly what I need and thank you for the breakdown. The exception being that it pastes each table below my default signature. This was the main reason the tables were pulling in reverse order. I've tried plugging in the first property in place of last, but it's throwing an error (91 : Object variable or With block variable not set) for the line: `wordDoc.Paragraphs.first.Previous.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture`

Comment: Code corrected to leave signature at the end

Comment: I see what you did there. Thank you so much for all of the help, this is fantastic and I *think* I'm starting to get it.